# Installing GitHub extension for VS2017 "This extension is not installable on any currently installed products"

Tags: visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

On an already installed Visual Studio Community 2017 (**version  15.9.5**), I am trying to add Github extension. While running the GitHub.VisualStudio.vsix installer, I am getting the above error. I have crosschecked my version from the Install logs, but unlike other questions on this topic, **version doesn't seem to be the problem.** [Versions supported are [14.0,17.0) and [15.0,17.0) for Community and IntegratedShell respectively]

I have already tried to edit the extension.vsixmanifest file, to add to the "Supported Products" section, but the changes did not reflect.

**The first time that I downloaded the installer it didn't show this error**, instead asked me to close all VS instances. For some reason, I couldn't afford to install it then and relaunched it later. After that, this error has been persistent. 
So,I tried deleting and downloading it again many times and tried to run it with  both VS open and closed. 
My Install Log file looks like this :

```
03-05-2019 21:30:41 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
03-05-2019 21:30:41 - -------------------------------------------
03-05-2019 21:30:41 - Initializing Install...
03-05-2019 21:30:42 - Extension Details...
03-05-2019 21:30:42 -   Identifier      : c3d3dc68-c977-411f-b3e8-03b0dccf7dfc
03-05-2019 21:30:42 -   Name            : GitHub Extension for Visual Studio
03-05-2019 21:30:42 -   Author          : GitHub, Inc
03-05-2019 21:30:42 -   Version         : 2.9.0.7614
03-05-2019 21:30:42 -   Description     : A Visual Studio Extension that brings the GitHub Flow into Visual Studio.
03-05-2019 21:30:42 -   Locale          : en-US
03-05-2019 21:30:42 -   MoreInfoURL     : https://visualstudio.github.com/
03-05-2019 21:30:42 -   InstalledByMSI  : False
03-05-2019 21:30:42 -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
03-05-2019 21:30:42 - 
03-05-2019 21:30:43 -   SignedBy        : GitHub, Inc.
03-05-2019 21:30:43 -   Certificate Info : [Subject]
  CN="GitHub, Inc.", O="GitHub, Inc.", L=San Francisco, S=California, C=US

[Issuer]
  CN=DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID Code Signing CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US

[Serial Number]
  013AA7BBB950DCCD25305F1602258B00

[Not Before]
  23-11-2016 05:30:00

[Not After]
  19-11-2019 17:30:00

[Thumbprint]
  C4FDF13659F49E57AC14774FDF45053F499F185F

03-05-2019 21:30:43 -   Supported Products : 
03-05-2019 21:30:43 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
03-05-2019 21:30:43 -           Version : [14.0,17.0)
03-05-2019 21:30:43 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntegratedShell
03-05-2019 21:30:43 -           Version : [15.0,17.0)
03-05-2019 21:30:43 - 
03-05-2019 21:30:43 -   References      : 
03-05-2019 21:30:43 -       -------------------------------------------------------
03-05-2019 21:30:43 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF.14.0
03-05-2019 21:30:43 -       Name         : Visual Studio MPF 14.0
03-05-2019 21:30:43 -       Version      : [14.0,)
03-05-2019 21:30:43 -       MoreInfoURL  : 
03-05-2019 21:30:43 -       Nested       : No
03-05-2019 21:30:43 - 
03-05-2019 21:30:43 -       -------------------------------------------------------
03-05-2019 21:30:43 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamExplorer.Extensions
03-05-2019 21:30:43 -       Name         : Team Explorer
03-05-2019 21:30:43 -       Version      : [14.0,)
03-05-2019 21:30:43 -       MoreInfoURL  : 
03-05-2019 21:30:43 -       Nested       : No
03-05-2019 21:30:43 - 
03-05-2019 21:30:43 - 
03-05-2019 21:30:43 - Searching for applicable products...
03-05-2019 21:30:44 - Found installed product - Global Location
03-05-2019 21:30:44 - Found installed product - ssms
03-05-2019 21:30:44 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817874/visual-studio-2017-is-not-detected-by-extensions-for-installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it results from `extensions.configurationchanged` file. You can try if `devenv /updateconfiguration` command and reinstall the .vsix can fix it.

**Steps to reproduce:**

I install the same extension and abort it **before** the installation succeeds. In this situation actually the .vsix is not successfully installed yet.But I can't reinstall it since the installer seems to not work to find my vs any more.

(In my opinion,the installer thinks the extension has been installed but actually it not)

**Workaround:**

Open your **Developer Command Prompt for VS2017**, and type command `devenv /updateconfiguration`, wait several seconds(maybe longer) until its execution finishes.

After that go `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions`, delete the `GitHub` folder (Which contains content of GitHub extension), and then rerun your xxx.vsix to check if it finds your VS2017 product. Hope it helps.

Comment: I did actually cancel installation, i believe your analysis is correct. i installed the same on my new machine and it got installed in the first go. 
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, glad to know it makes some help:)